# Cannot update a property in an embedded Array in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm working on a commenting system with mongoose/n, 
users can comment, and like in reddit, users should vote each comment up or down.
and i have the following comment scheme:

```
var commentSchema = new Schema({
  text: String,

  level: { type: Number, min: 0, max: 30, default: 0},
  slug: String,
  full_slug: String,

  discussion_id: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Uranus' },
  parent_id: {type: Schema.ObjectId,ref: 'Comment'},

  score: [{
        upvote: {type: Number,min: 0,max: 9000},
        downvote: {type: Number,min: 0,max: 9000},
        voter: {type: Schema.ObjectId,ref: 'Account'}
    }],

  updated: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  created: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  author: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Account' },
});
```

it works just fine, but i have no clue, how to update the score-array. it just doesn't work.
Here is the sample json-data i got:

```
{
"__v" : 0,
"_id" : ObjectId("52a0d4ff779edff16d000006"),
"author" : ObjectId("529dfdda6b2d7a450c000009"),
"created" : ISODate("2013-12-05T19:33:19.229Z"),
"discussion_id" : ObjectId("529f7b04cbab31cc3e000004"),
"full_slug" : "2013.12.05.19.33.19:e1CDx79g8",
"level" : 0,
"score" : [ 
    {
        "upvote" : 1,
        "downvote" : 0,
        "voter" : ObjectId("529dfdda6b2d7a450c000009"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("52a0d4ff779edff16d000007")
    }, 
    {
        "upvote" : 0,
        "downvote" : 1,
        "voter" : ObjectId("52a0d9883027a89d6e000002"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("52a0d9903027a89d6e000004")
    }, 
    {
        "upvote" : 0,
        "downvote" : 1,
        "voter" : ObjectId("52a0d99a3027a89d6e000005"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("52a0d9a63027a89d6e000007")
    }
],
"slug" : "e1CDx79g8",
"text" : "A Comment",
"updated" : ISODate("2013-12-05T19:33:19.229Z")
}
```

so, i just update the comment by

```
var query = {
  'score.voter': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(String('52a0d9883027a89d6e000002'))
};
Comment.update( query, {$set: {"score.$.upvote": 10}} )
```

The problem is, that it's just not updating.

i know, there are a few other questions regarding this problem, but all solutions are not working for me. i hope someone can help me.

**UPDATE:**

Found the problem, Seems like you have to have a callback on the update function like this:

```
Comment.update( query, {$set: {"score.$.upvote": 10}}, { multi: false }, function(err,n){
    console.log("affected rows:", n)
});
```

Comment: FYI $set is redundant in mongoose, try changing to...
`Comment.update( query, {"score.$.upvote": 10} )`

Comment: tested it, but still no change.

Comment: Sorry I had re-read the docs and you had it right with the $ positional operator. Have you tested your query with a find() to ensure it is matching anything? Also if you match more than one document you'll need to add the {multi : true} options if you want all matches to be updated.

Comment: One other thing you may want to do is look at using the $inc operator instead of setting the value.

Comment: thanks, the $set is just for testing purposes. i have tested that i find something, and it did. i have just found this for embdding documents: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/embedded-documents.html, but i think, it should work either way. but i will test the official way.

Comment: I found the problem. seems like i need to have a callback on the update function. but i don't understand why? can someone explane that to me?

Comment: I think this is because the APIs chainable an until a callback function is supplied it doesn't know if you're done chaining. Once a callback is seen as the last arg or supplied in.exec() then the actual call is made to mongo.